# Installation of Apache OpenOffice ends because I do not have superuser privileges

Tags: openoffice.org

During the installation process of Apache OpenOffice 4.1.1, when I enter the command "dpkg -i *.deb" the installation ended with the following message: dpkg: error: this operation needs superuser privileges.
How can I solve this?

Thank you for your help.

Artur

Comment: Why do you want to install OpenOffice when you have Libreoffice pre-installed in Ubuntu? Also you need a `sudo` befor that dpkg command.

Answer (score 0):

You must run the command as root with temporary permits, prefixing the command sudo.

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

I also prefer Apache OpenOffice to LibreOffice.

Answer (score 0):

You know how Software Center requires your password? What it's doing behind the scenes is running the command as a superuser. It temporarily escalates your privileges so that it can write to locations outside your home folder where you wouldn't normally have permissions to do so. This is equivalent to what people refer to as "running as root" though Ubuntu's root account is typically disabled. This is what the `sudo` command will do for you. Any time software is being installed, this will be required.

tl;dr `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/your.deb`

Note that you will have to manually update a package installed this way, so it's not ideal from a maintenance perspective. You can get around this for some Ubuntu versions by using a PPA. UpUbuntu.com has one you can use by doing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/openoffice
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache-openoffice
```

Be aware, though, that these are not officially supported and may have problems.

More on sudo [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) and installing software [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware).